# Android, sqlite database finding two values in the two columns and the resulting value

Tags: android, database, sqlite

im constructing an android application which use a large pre populated datbase of 910,000 records which includes 4 columns. These columns are windspeed, latitude, longitude and _id. What im trying to do is construct an sqlite query that finds a lav value in the latitude column and long (longitude) value in the longitude and the windspeed at which these two columns meet.

So the table would look something like this:

_id..............Latitude..................Longitude..............WindSpeed
 1..................-9.4869363.............61.3704805..............7
2.................-7.6257292...............60.9958851..............8
3.................-9.4869363................60.9958851..............10

so if i was use the above table the lat value i would want to find would -9.4869363 and the long value would be 60.9958851 and thus the windspeed would be the line that both of these meet e.g from the table line 3 and thus the wind speed is 10

To do this ive tried using this line of code but i dont think it is correct

```
 public class MyDatabase extends SQLiteAssetHelper {

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "WindSpeed.sqlite";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String LAT_VAL = "Latitude";
private static final String LONG_VAL = "Longitude";
private static final String WIND_SPEED= "Speed10m";
private static final String ROW_ID=     " _id";
double lat= 3.52;
double Long = 65.42;
public MyDatabase(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

   public Cursor getWindSpeed2(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

    String [] sqlSelect = {WIND_SPEED,}; 
    String sqlTables = "noabl_10m_out";
    String whereClause = "LAT_VAL = ? AND LONG_VAL = ?";
    String[] whereArgs = new String[] {
        "lat",
        "Long"
    };

    qb.setTables(sqlTables);
    Cursor d = qb.query(db, sqlSelect, whereClause, whereArgs,
            null, null, null);

    d.moveToFirst();

    return d;


   }
  }
```

Is this wrong, ive searched far and wind and i just keep getting confused tbh so any help would be massive thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are not using the column names but instead the variable names.

Try to change the whereClause to:

```
String whereClause = LAT_VAL + "=? AND " + LONG_VAL + "=?";
```

Also the whereArgs to:

```
String[] whereArgs = new String[] {
    String.valueOf(lat),
    String.valueOf(Long)
};
```

There are many mistakes in your code and I'm starting to think that you have no idea what you're doing.. Unnecessary comma here:

```
String [] sqlSelect = {WIND_SPEED,};
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
 String whereClause = "LAT_VAL = ? AND LONG_VAL = ?";
```

to

```
  String whereClause = LAT_VAL+" = ? AND "+LONG_VAL+" = ?";
```

and

```
String[] whereArgs = new String[] 
{
    "-9.4869363",
    "60.9958851"
};
```

to

```
String[] whereArgs = new String[] 
{
    "lat",
    "Long"
};
```

`LAT_VAL` and `LONG_VAL` are variable that you use to store the columns name so they should be outside the quotes and `whereArgs` needs to contain the values that you want to compare

Comment: Okay thanks, how would i get the wind speed value at that site then would it be the cursors value ? or is that just a pointer to value

Comment: `WIND_SPEED` is the column whose value will be returned to you.

Comment: Yes that is the plan, i just want the wind speed where the values for lat and long meet.